# 401K Enrollment Benefits

Tags: investing, 401k, roth-401k, benefits

I have enrolled in my 401K plan from 2016 onward. While looing into the investment portal, right now I am having only 68K but I contributed for 69K. Is it still worth in enrolling 401K?

If I invested this amount in gold then my returns might be more but Is it OK if the current amount is less than the invested amount?

I am planning to retire after 30 years.

I am not seeing any growth right now.

Comment: How many years do you have until retirement?

Comment: Planning to retire after 30 years. @shoover

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"right now" is a very strange time. If you've invested consistently in, say, the S&P 500 over the past 4 years, about half of your investments would be made below the current level and half above, so it's not shocking that you're at about the same level of your investments. (I'm assuming that you don't get a company match or that you're accounting for it separately) And gold is at a 5-year high, so if you had invested in gold (presuming you *can* do that in your 401(k)), then yes you'd be better off.

But that's hindsight. You have $68k in a retirement account, regardless of how much of that is contribution and how much is growth. So the only question is, what should you invest in going forward?

This is not the first (or the last) large market drop. On average we've seen one about every 10-12 years (1987, 2001, 2008, 2020).  In between, the market has rebounded and grown significantly past its previous highs. So history tells us that it will probably happen again.

That said, if you are close to retirement (like within 5 years), then it's time to start putting *some* of your investments in less volatile markets like bonds or CDs. If you have a long time to retirement, you have the ability to take risk by investing in equities. If you don't have the *appetite* for such risk, then you can diversify now, but you could be missing out on some gains (lower risk means lower rewards on average).

And stay away from gold - it's a volatile commodity that does not show long-term growth (if you had invested in gold in 1980 and left it alone, you'd have about the same or less today) it's at a high now, but very likely it's because investors have "fled" to gold away from the equity collapse. Once equities start rebounding (and I believe they will), gold will likely drop.

Comment: Thanks for your comment and Can I save after 30 years of investment?

Comment: What does "Can I save after 30 years of investment?" mean?

Comment: @Test I'm not sure what you mean. If you're asking if continuing to invest in your 401(k) will be profitable after 30 years, then the answer is most probably yes. The S&P 500 Total Return (i.e. w reinvesting dividends) has never averaged less than 8% in any 30-year period in its history (using end-of-year values at least).